# Como seleccionar/deseleccionar un renglon en una Grilla de seleccion multiple sin importar el lugar de TAPeo?

Tags: genexus, genexus18

Tenemos un Grid que tiene implementada la selección múltiple.
En el Grid observamos que solamente selecciona el renglón deseado, sí y solo sí se apoya el dedo sobre el checkbox.

Si el usuario final hace “tap” en medio del renglón deseado no se selecciona…

Cómo se puede hacer para que el renglón que es “TAPeado” se seleccione/deseleccione sin importar si apoyó el dedo dentro del checkbox ó cerca del checkbox?

Si TAPeo dentro del checkbox:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si TAPeo en la mitad del renglón:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Ulises, recuerda que es importante agregar el código que te encuentres realizando, saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pude solucionar utilizando el evento TAP del Grid1Table

```
Event Grid1Table.Tap
    composite
        //logica para que toque donde toque el renglon sea seleccionado/deseleccionado
        &indexSelectedRow = &ConsultaRutasAprob_OUT.fs_P5543280_W5543280A.data.gridData.rowset.CurrentItem.rowIndex.Integer() + 1
        grid1.Select(&indexSelectedRow)
    endcomposite
Endevent
```

Answer (score 0):

No sé bien como lo tenés programado. Mirando la pantalla parece una variable (checkbox) que se acepta (no es readonly).
Lo que haría es configurar en la grilla el "Default action" (https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?20424,Default+Action+property) un evento que haga algo como:

```
Event 'Seleccionar'
   If &Seleccionada
      &Seleccionada=False
   else
       &Seleccionada=True
   endif
Endevent
```